# How do I stack more than two arrows in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

The command `\rightrightarrows` (from `amssymb`) draws two arrows, one on top of another. How do I get three arrows arranged in a similar fashion? An example of this (and other fancy arrow stackings) appears on page 3 of [this paper](http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2007/tmfproc/Chapter07/douglas-sheaves.pdf), for which a source file unfortunately does not seem to be available. Commands like `\stackrel` and `\overset` do not size or space things properly.

Comment: I’m rather surprised that there is no package with these symbols. For three arrows there is even a Unicode symbol (which [`unicode-math`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) exposes as `\rightthreearrows`).

Answer (score 11):

Use `\substack`

```
$X\substack{\rightarrow\\[-1em] \rightarrow \\[-1em] \rightarrow} Y$
```

you can change `[-1em]` to be any value as you want.

*(Added by Hendrik Vogt:)* With

```
$X \mathrel{\substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow \\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow}} Y$
```

you get something quite close to `\rightrightarrows`.

Answer (score 7):

How about the following?

```
\newcommand\rightthreearrow{%
        \mathrel{\vcenter{\mathsurround0pt
                \ialign{##\crcr
                        \noalign{\nointerlineskip}$\rightarrow$\crcr
                        \noalign{\nointerlineskip}$\rightarrow$\crcr
                        \noalign{\nointerlineskip}$\rightarrow$\crcr
                }%
        }}%
}
```

[image: example]

This is basically how `\overbrace` works except that it uses a fill and a `\vbox` instead of a `\vcenter`.

Comment: You could add some spacing to cause the arrows to not overlap. I didn't even notice it until just now though.

Comment: I think you should use `\mathrel`, not `\mathop` for correct spacing (`\rightrightarrows` are `\mathrel`).

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks. Fixed. (I didn't change the picture though.)

Answer (score 5):

Use TikZ!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\triplerightarrow}{%
\tikz[minimum height=0ex]
  \path[->]
   node (a)            {}
   node (b) at (1em,0) {}
  (a.north)  edge (b.north)
  (a.center) edge (b.center)
  (a.south)  edge (b.south);%
}

\begin{document}

\[
A \triplerightarrow B
\]
\end{document}
```

The `minimum height=0ex` doesn't do anything.  I included it to show how to increase the separation of the arrows if desired.  To get longer arrows, increase the `1em` (this could be made an optional parameter, of course, and with a bit of work could be made so that there was a(nother) parameter specifying some text on top whereupon the arrows scaled to the correct length).

Comment: TikZ is kind of overkill, I think, and the arrows look different from `\rightrightarrows`.

Comment: @Hendrik: On the first point I concede, except for the fact that I tend to load TikZ for every document nowadays so as it's already there, why not use it for this construction?  On the second, I don't see _that_ much difference.  The lines look a little crisper in the TikZ one at 400 magnification, and are perhaps 1pt too long (corrected with `shorten >=1pt`).  If you want the arrows to touch, use `inner sep=.3em`.  I think that a TikZ arrow looks much better than that typeset by, say, `\xrightarrow` so I'd count the discrepancy as a minus for `\rightrightarrows` than the other way around.

Comment: Well, of course it's a good question which arrow looks _better_. But you conceded that you _do_ see a difference, and that was my point. If you use different arrows (e.g. the simple `\to`), then they should look the _same_, have the same spacing and so on. And it's quite hard to get it so close with TikZ that you can't see a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can mess around with XY-pic, the `\xymatrix` command in particular could be used. You might begin with the [XY-pic User's Guide (pdf)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf).

For example, if you `\input xy` and `\xyoption{all}` in your preamble, then

```
 \[\xymatrix{
  A\ar@<1ex>[r]\ar[r]\ar@<-1ex>[r] & B
 }\]
```

Will produce 3 arrows from A to B.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by `\threesim` in symbols-a4, which stacks three `\sim` symbols, here's a solution for stacking and vertically centering a symbol three times:

```
\newcommand*{\triple}[2][.1ex]{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip%
  \hbox{$#2$}\vskip#1\hbox{$#2$}\vskip#1\hbox{$#2$}}}}
```

You may use it to stack three right or left arrows or others, just a dot for example:

```
\newcommand*{\triplerightarrow}{\triple{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand*{\tripleleftarrow}{\triple{\leftarrow}}
\newcommand*{\tripledot}{\triple[-.6ex]{\cdot}}
```

Example:

```
$X\triplerightarrow Y\tripledot\tripleleftarrow Z$
```

[image]

You might adjust the spacing using the optional argument, perhaps choose another arrow with a smaller tip if you like.