# Uniform convergence symbol (arrow on top of arrow, same size)

Tags: symbols, amsmath, arrows, math-operators

I am looking for a symbol that looks like two arrows of the same size, one on top of the other with (possibly) a letter on top, this is my paint sketch of it:

[image]

I've tried something like

```
\xrightarrow{\xrightarrow{n}}
```

and similar combinations but it always makes one arrow smaller.

I've seen this symbol used to say that a sequence of functions converges uniformly to another function.

Comment: You can use the solution here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114233/no-xrightrightarrowab

Comment: The solution there works, but it doesn't look good when inline. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30958/101651

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need it in smaller math styles, then this could work...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\newcommand\frightarrow{\scalebox{1}[.4]{$\rightarrow$}}
\newcommand\darrow[1][]{\mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{\stackanchor[1pt]{\frightarrow}{\frightarrow}}{\scriptstyle#1}}}
\begin{document}
$A\darrow[n] B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a composite alternative

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,amssymb}
\stackMath
\newcommand\frightarrow{\scalebox{1}[.3]{$\rule[.45ex]{2ex}{1.5pt}%
  \kern-.2ex{\blacktriangleright}$}}
\newcommand\darrow[1][]{\mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{\stackanchor[1pt]{\frightarrow}{\frightarrow}}{\scriptstyle#1}}}
\begin{document}
$A\darrow[n] B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With the `amssymb` package you can just use `\rightrightarrows`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[A\overset{n}{\rightrightarrows}B\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and where is *n* above arrows?

Comment: @Zarko :-) I have put the "n" :-)))))) a contribute for a new user.

Comment: Oh, dear @Sebastiano, you are so good soul. I try to encourage her to this . Well, I will do now with up-voting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Cheating" would be writing it as

```
f_n(x)^\rightarrow_\rightarrow f(x)
```

which results in the following formula:

[image]