# Make \rightrightarrows longer?

Tags: arrows

Is there a way to make the \rightrightarrows symbol longer? I tried

`f_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\rightrightarrows}f`

but I am unhappy with the result:

[image: My try]

I want something similar to this (using the extarrows package):

`f_n\xlongrightarrow{n\to\infty}f`

[image]

Comment: Try this:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25053/213149 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114242/213149

Comment: @antshar thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer there is another possibility using tikz-cd package to have you desidered output. The first example use the CM (computer modern font) and the Euler math fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}
\begin{document}
First and second example in \textit{math-mode},
\[
        \begin{tikzcd}f_n \arrow[r, "n\to\infty"] &[2em] f \end{tikzcd}\]
\[       \begin{tikzcd}f_n \arrow[r, "n\to\infty"] &[.5em] f\end{tikzcd} 
\]
Third example inline mathmode $\begin{tikzcd} f_n \arrow[r, "n\to\infty"] &[.2em] f\end{tikzcd}$  if you want, after, to write a comment.
\end{document}
```

With the second example you have, the Palatino fonts for the text (`\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}`) that they adapt with it using [Euler](http://ftp.riken.jp/tex-archive/fonts/eulervm/doc/latex/eulervm/eulervm.pdf) math fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}
\begin{document}
First and second example in \textit{math-mode},
\[
        \begin{tikzcd}f_n \arrow[r, "n\to\infty"] &[2em] f \end{tikzcd}\]
\[       \begin{tikzcd}f_n \arrow[r, "n\to\infty"] &[.5em] f\end{tikzcd} 
\]
Third example inline mathmode $\begin{tikzcd} f_n \arrow[r, "n\to\infty"] &[.2em] f\end{tikzcd}$  if you want, after, to write a comment.
\end{document}
```

[image]