# Double \rightsquigarrow?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I came across this symbol in a probability book but don’t know how to type it.[image: white circle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This is not a complete solution. As pointed out in the comments by Ruixi Zhang, `substack` by default puts its contents in `\scriptstyle`. So unless you manually specify the correct math level size you want (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle` etc) the size of the arrows isn't truly correct and won't scale automatically.

**Original answer**

Here is a proposal using `substack`.

You can adjust the vertical separation between the arrows by adjusting `[-2em]` after `\\`. I've also wrapped the `substack` in `mathrel`. This modifies the spacing around the `substack` to that of a relation, such as `=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\doublerightsquigarrow}{\mathrel{\substack{\displaystyle\rightsquigarrow\\[-2em]\displaystyle\rightsquigarrow}}}

\begin{document}
\[
(\mathbb{F}_n - F)  \doublerightsquigarrow  \mathcal{H} \circ F
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m afraid that I have to disagree with your solution: 1) `\substack` puts its contents in `\scriptstyle`, so the `\rightsquigarrow` is not at the correct size. 2) Because of 1), when your `\doublerightsquigarrow` is used in first- or second-level math scripts, it will still be at the same size.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Are any of these solutions suitable? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/how-do-i-stack-more-than-two-arrows-in-math-mode

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions in your linked post addressed the scaling problem. [The one by S. Boonto](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7267/164314) noticed this and added `\textstyle` inside `\substack`, but still it was not a complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative to @Milo’s solution, which takes care of getting the correct size in each of `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. No additional packages needed.

The solution is essentially [stacking arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2656/164314). However, none of the solutions suggested in that linked post addressed the sizing problem. Note that if you were to use @Milo’s solution in `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`, you should probably add `\textstyle` in `\substack` as in [@SBoonto’s solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7267/164314).

To properly design the separation between the two arrows, I took inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199778/164314) by @wipet. But instead of `\vbox`, we should use `\vcenter` to construct our symbol. Note that the resulting double arrows are closer and, IMHO, more suitable to be viewed as *one* symbol.

Also, note that I called the new symbol `\doublerightsquigarrows` instead of `\doublerightsquigarrow`. The `\stack@two@symbols` macro can be used to create other stacked symbols (Of course, you use it within a pair of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% no need for `amsmath'

\linespread{2}\selectfont% for better visual

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\doublerightsquigarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\mathchoice
    {\stack@two@symbols{text}{display}{\rightsquigarrow}{\rightsquigarrow}}%
    {\stack@two@symbols{text}{text}{\rightsquigarrow}{\rightsquigarrow}}%
    {\stack@two@symbols{script}{script}{\rightsquigarrow}{\rightsquigarrow}}%
    {\stack@two@symbols{scriptscript}{scriptscript}{\rightsquigarrow}{\rightsquigarrow}}%
  }%
}
% just for fun
\newcommand*{\crazyarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\mathchoice
    {\stack@two@symbols{text}{display}{\mapsto}{\Leftarrow}}%
    {\stack@two@symbols{text}{text}{\mapsto}{\Leftarrow}}%
    {\stack@two@symbols{script}{script}{\mapsto}{\Leftarrow}}%
    {\stack@two@symbols{scriptscript}{scriptscript}{\mapsto}{\Leftarrow}}%
  }%
}
% syntax of \stack@two@symbols{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}:
%    #1: font dimension parameters, `text', `script' or `scriptscript';
%    #2: math styles, `display', `text', `script' or `scriptscript';
%    #3: top symbol;
%    #4: bottom symbol.
\def\stack@two@symbols#1#2#3#4{%
  \vcenter{%
  \baselineskip=\fontdimen17\csname#1font\endcsname2\advance\baselineskip by\fontdimen14\csname#1font\endcsname2%
  \halign{\hfil$\csname#2style\endcsname##$\hfil\cr#3\cr#4\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \makebox[10em][r]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}:
  $\csname#1\endcsname \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \log \log n}} (\mathbb{F}_n - F) \doublerightsquigarrows \mathcal{H} \circ F$%
}
\newcommand*{\testcrazy}[1]{%
  \makebox[10em][r]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}:
  $\csname#1\endcsname \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \log \log n}} (\mathbb{F}_n - F) \crazyarrows \mathcal{H} \circ F$%
}

\begin{document}
Double rightsquig arrows\par
\test{displaystyle}\par
\test{textstyle}\par
\test{scriptstyle}\par
\test{scriptscriptstyle}\par
Crazy arrows\par
\testcrazy{displaystyle}\par
\testcrazy{textstyle}\par
\testcrazy{scriptstyle}\par
\testcrazy{scriptscriptstyle}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacking arrows]

Answer (score 3):

The vertical gap between the two arrows is governed by the `12\LMpt` (optional argument to `\stackanchor`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\doublerightsquigarrow{%
  \mathrel{\ThisStyle{\def\stacktype{L}\ensurestackMath{
    \stackanchor[12\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\rightsquigarrow}{\SavedStyle\rightsquigarrow}
  }}}
}
\begin{document}
\[
                    (\mathbb{F}_n - F)  \doublerightsquigarrow  \mathcal{H} \circ F
\]
\[
\scriptstyle        (\mathbb{F}_n - F)  \doublerightsquigarrow  \mathcal{H} \circ F
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle  (\mathbb{F}_n - F)  \doublerightsquigarrow  \mathcal{H} \circ F
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can easily reproduce the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\log\log n}}
(\mathbb{F}_n-F)
\mathrel{\begin{matrix}
\rightsquigarrow \\
\rightsquigarrow
\end{matrix}}
\mathcal{H}\circ F
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you prefer less vertical space (and you should), here's how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
% find a better name
\newcommand{\doublerightsquigarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\double@rightsquigarrow\relax}%
}
\newcommand\double@rightsquigarrow[2]{%
  \vcenter{
    \m@th % no math surround
    \baselineskip=\z@ % let \lineskip play
    \lineskiplimit=\z@
    \lineskip=1pt % or whatever
    \hbox{$#1\rightsquigarrow$}
    \hbox{$#1\rightsquigarrow$}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\log\log n}}\,(\mathbb{F}_n-F)
\doublerightsquigarrow
\mathcal{H}\circ F
\]

$A\doublerightsquigarrow B$

$\scriptstyle A\doublerightsquigarrow B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\doublerightsquigarrow B$

\end{document}
```

[image]